# Group routers into external files in Iris, Party

Tags: go

I am learning Golang and decided to try out Iris as it is currently the most popular framework, just out of curiosity.

How do I group routes into external files?

main.go

```
// See apiRoutes here
apiRouter := iris.Party("/api", apiRoutes)
```

api_routes.go

```
func apiRoutes() {

    iris.Get("/blog", ...)

    iris.Get("/news", ...)
}
```

So a call to `/api/blog` would be processed within `api_routes.go` inside the `iris.Get("/blog")` function.

Update: My current project structure is like so. I would also like to continuously nest my routes:

```
|- Routes
    |- api_routes.go
    |- blog
    |- blog_routes.go
        |- posts
            blog_posts_routes.go
        |- categories
            blog_categories_routes.go
|- main.go
```

Comment: Iris is _definitely not_ the most popular Go framework. You can search for many articles documenting the behavior of the "sole" developer.

Comment: @JimB could you link me to some please? I just jumped in so any advice is welcome

Comment: http://www.florinpatan.ro/2016/10/why-you-should-not-use-iris-for-your-go.html. Beside the behavior of the author, IMHO simply having a project that routinely rewrites the history of the master branch makes it a non-starter for anything serious.

Comment: @JimB well that looks shitty. I'll stick on iris for the start just to get the basics of Go. Can you recommend any other frameworks to go with? A powerful template renderer is very important (looping through data, including dynamic partial templates)

Comment: I usually don't like full frameworks for Go, and only pull in individual components as needed. There's a decent list here that may help: https://github.com/avelino/awesome-go#web-frameworks

Comment: @JimB, this might not be the best place for this conversation but could you expand a bit more on why you do not like full frameworks for Go?

Comment: disclaimer, I don't do a lot of web development; but I usually find complete frameworks aren't needed, the std lib is very complete, and you can piece together smaller external packages when you do need their functionality. For example, you're probably using one of the [template packages here](https://github.com/avelino/awesome-go#template-engines) in iris, which you could just import yourself if you don't want to use "html/template". Decreasing the number of external dependencies you have can also make long-term support of your codebase easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to keep routes in separate file then you have two options

1. Both main.go and api_routes.go MUST be in same package, probably in
   your case it should be "package main"
2. If you are keeping api_routes.go in separate package then you have to import that package in main.go.

Comment: See my update. Could you provide some basic code example on importing function to be used as a `HandlerFunc` ?

Comment: I wrote a small sample based on your folder structure [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1ZJ-CiBKRTBcTRBZUt1dW5zVm8/view?usp=sharing)